# Свёкольный или свекольный?

Tags: ударение

Свёкольный или свекОльный? Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно поставить ударение.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я произношу слово "свекольный" с ударением на втором слоге.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильность ударения можно проверить на сайте Грамота.ру.

Правильно: свЁкла - свекОльный, здесь О - беглая ударная гласная, сравнить: игла - игОльный, польза - полЕзный.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь два вопроса. На первый вопрос ответ — свекОльный. На второй:

- Если Вы имели в виду постановку ударения в слове, у которого вы знаете написание, это сложная тема; для этого есть орфоэпические словари, а также некоторые правила, но они не всегда работают. Следует как раз запоминать ударение вместе с самими словами. Насколько я помню, я читал(а), что, когда ударная Е (в т. ч. возникшая из Ь, но не Ѣ) стояла перед твёрдым согласным, она превратилась в Ё; это можно попытаться использовать для определения ударения (если бы в слове «свекольный» было ударение на первом слоге, оно было бы «свёкольный»), но это не всегда работает: в слове «елка», по этой логике, должно быть ударение на втором слоге (т. к., согласно ответу, который я видел(а), оно родственно «ель», а не «есть»), но оно на первом.
- Если Вы имели в виду постановку ударения в устной речи, т.е. что это вообще значит, насколько я понимаю, ударный слог произносится немного громче и длиннее. При этом важнее, наверное, громкость.